# Pre-fill form field with data from prior page in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, mailboxer

I recently added `Mailboxer` to my Rails app and have everything working well.

However, I want to be able to create a new message by clicking a "Message Me" button on a User's page and then have the recipient filled in already (with the User from the prior page) when the form for creating the message loads.

The particular field in question:

```
<%= select_tag 'recipients', recipients_options, multiple: true, class: 'new_message_recipients_field' %>
```

And for reference, `recipients_options` probably won't come into play in this scenario, but it is the list of all Users--which I use primarily when I'm creating a Message from anywhere but a User page--and is defined in my Messages helper

```
def recipients_options
  s = ''
  User.all.each do |user|
    s << "<option value='#{user.id}'>#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}</option>"
  end
  s.html_safe
end
```

And my `messages_controller.rb`:

```
def new
end

def create
  recipients = User.where(id: params['recipients'])
  conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, params[:message][:body], params[:message][:subject]).conversation
  flash[:success] = "Message has been sent!"
  redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
end
```

I already have the link to the New Message form on each User page...

`<%= link_to 'Message me', new_message_path %>`

But I don't know how to pre-fill the recipient in the subsequent form.

Any suggestions for how would I go about this?

Comment: Why are you using a select tag?

Comment: @kendotwill, because I want the message to be able to be sent to multiple recipients, if the sending User chooses to. In the particular use case I'm referencing in this question, I want the recipient field to be pre-filled with one option (the User whose "Message Me" button I clicked), though if the sending User then wants to add more recipients that's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `link_to` code to this:

```
<%= link_to 'Message me', new_message_path(recipient_id: @user.id) %>
```

In `messages#new` action, add this code:

```
def new
  @users = User.all
end
```

And, in message form, replace the select_tag with this:

```
<%= select_tag 'recipients', options_from_collection_for_select(@users, :id, :first_name, params[:recipient_id]), multiple: true, class: 'new_message_recipients_field' %>
```

I made some changes in recipients select. You can use `options_from_collection_for_select` method to generate that options instead implement your own helper.

Reference: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select

Comment: I tried your answer and it gave me this error: `undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass`. I also edited my question to include the `messages_controller.rb` I currently have (not including your suggested changes). How would you integrate your changes with what I currently have in `def create`?

Comment: @Andrew, To use the changes I suggested in your views, instantiate `@users` and `@recipes` instance variables in your `new` action too. This should get rid of the error

Comment: adding those two lines to both `new` and `create` does get rid of the error, but still doesn't populate the field. Why might that be? Could you edit your answer to show the full `messages_controller.rb` so I can make sure I'm doing it all as you intend?

Comment: This should work. Please, debug the `new` actions coming from an user page. The `@recipes` variable should be an array with the user. If ok, check the output of `options_from_collection_for_select`, it should be some options (one for each `User`) with the one corresponding to the user with `selected` attribute.

Comment: it doesn't seem like it's pulling any of the user data for `@recipes`...when I try to simply print the data on the form page it only returned `#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:0x007f962d218fe8>`.

Comment: This right! Do you know what [Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) is? print `@recipes.to_a`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69161/discussion-between-andrew-and-rodrigo).

Comment: thanks for all your help! Is there a way to clean up the URL so it doesn't look like `http://localhost:3000/messages/new?recipient_id=1` when I access it via one of the Message Me buttons, but rather just `http://localhost:3000/messages/new`, which is how it looks when I simply navigate to `new_message_path`?

Comment: @Andrew - I made the edit you tried to make based on the [chat discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21052440#21052440) between yourself and Rodrigo so that the answer would be up to date.  Rodrigo, I only edited because it was your suggestion; roll back if you disagree.

Comment: @WilliamPrice - I had edited it exactly as you now have, why did it not go though when I did it?

Comment: @Andrew other reviewers declined your edit. They might not have gone through the chat transcript to see the full context.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mailboxer and I'm able to, from a Listing page, contact the seller.

The user clicks on the contact seller button on Listing page and in on next page the To: form is filled out with seller's name.

I have the same Create method as in your message controller. but in NEW method i have this:

```
MessageController

  def new
    @chosen_recipient = User.find_by(id: params[:to].to_i) if params[:to]
  end
```

The contact button on my listing page:

```
</p>
  <strong>Contact Seller about "<%= @listing.title %>"</strong></br>
  <%= link_to "Send message to #{@listing.user.name}", new_message_path(to: @listing.user.id), class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm' %>
<p>
```

The NEW message form:

```
<%= form_tag messages_path, method: :post do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'message[subject]', 'Subject' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'message[subject]', nil, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'message[body]', 'Message' %>
    <%= text_area_tag 'message[body]', nil, cols: 3, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'recipients', 'Choose recipients' %>
    <%= select_tag 'recipients', recipients_options(@chosen_recipient), multiple: true, class: 'form-control chosen-it' %>
  </div>

  <%= submit_tag 'Send', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps!